# inserts 'Array' into mysql table individual fields(not to raws)

Tags: php, mysql

my code's

```
$output.= '<div class="body">'.$message.'</div>';
echo $output;//output the email body
```

---

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = str_get_html("$output"); 
foreach($html->find('tr') as $e) {
    $b = $e->find('td',1)->plaintext;
$EMailArr[] =$b ;
}

$value_string3= implode("','", $EMailArr);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (`a`,`b`,`c`,`d`,`e`,`f`,`g`,`h`,`i`) VALUES($value_string3)");
print "INSERT INTO test (`a`,`b`,`c`,`d`,`e`,`f`,`g`,`h`,`i`) VALUES($value_string3)";
```

outputs..
Array

```
(
    [0] => MD-MAL_MSAG5200_01 - MD-Malwana - ZTE
    [1] =>   CRITICAL
    [2] => MD-MAL_MSAG5200_01 - MD-Malwana - ZTE Isolated
    [3] => All customers(49) in above MD-MAL_MSAG5200_01 DSLAM/=3D MSAN  
    [4] => PENDING
    [5] => =  FMT-BB(A)
    [6] =>   OPEN
    [7] => PENDING
    [8] => Informed to DGM :idsmanjuka@gmail.com 
)
```

INSERT INTO test (`a`,`b`,`c`,`d`,`e`,`f`,`g`,`h`,`i`) VALUES(MD-MAL_MSAG5200_01 - MD-Malwana - ZTE',' CRITICAL','MD-MAL_MSAG5200_01 - MD-Malwana - ZTE Isolated','All customers(49) in above MD-MAL_MSAG5200_01 DSLAM/=3D MSAN ','PENDING','= FMT-BB(A)',' OPEN','PENDING','Informed to DGM :idsmanjuka@gmail.com )

Comment: "Network Affected", is this your column name?

Comment: Database and table names cannot contain “/”, “\”, “.”, or characters that are not permitted in file names.

Comment: what's TRUE with your code ? :)

Answer (score 2):

Use backticks ` for your column names (as it contains space in it).

```
INSERT INTO test (`Network Affected`,`Fault Type`,`Fault Detail Description`,`Systems/Service     
Affected`,`Expected Clearance`,`Fault Reported By`,`Fault Status`,`Fault Cleared Date`,`Details of 
Actions Taken by FMT-BB`) VALUES ('MD-MAL_MSAG5200_01 - MD-Malwana - ZTE',' CRITICAL','MD-
MAL_MSAG5200_01 - MD-Malwana - ZTE Isolated','All customers(49) in above MD-
MAL_MSAG5200_01 DSLAM/=3D MSAN ','PENDING','= FMT-BB(A)',' OPEN','PENDING','Informed to 
DGM :kapuru@slt.com.lk' )
```

Also as mention by @Harry in comment, make sure your string values are surrounded by `'`

**Warning:** It's a very poor practice to have column name with space.

Comment: And OP is missing `'` on some of his values.

Comment: thanks every one.iam new one to php and mysql ald also the software filed..., it's working for this query.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => MD-MAL_MSAG5200_01 - MD-Malwana - ZTE
    [1] =>   CRITICAL
    [2] => MD-MAL_MSAG5200_01 - MD-Malwana - ZTE Isolated
    [3] => All customers(49) in above MD-MAL_MSAG5200_01 DSLAM/=3D MSAN  
    [4] => PENDING
    [5] => =  FMT-BB(A)
    [6] =>   OPEN
    [7] => PENDING
    [8] => Informed to DGM :kapuru@slt.com.lk  
)

Comment: Hello, Kindly ask another question for a new problem.

Comment: thank u all for your great support and quick response for my quiz.and also thank u stack-overflow also.this is my first time i solve it "there's a error in my implode .its working fine....

Answer (score 2):

- Database and table names cannot contain `/`, `\`, `.`, or characters that are not permitted in file names.
- Database, table, and column names cannot end with space characters.

To know more about - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

Answer (score 1):

You are missing single quotes in some of your values (first and last).
Also - the column names don't seem to by valid column names.

The correct syntax for INSERT statement is 
INSERT INTO TEST (column_name1,column_name2) VALUES ('value1','value2')

It seems that instead of column_name1 and column_name2 you are using column description.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO test( `Network Affected` , `Fault Type` , `Fault Detail Description` , `Systems/Service Affected` , `Expected Clearance` , `Fault Reported By` , `Fault Status` , `Fault Cleared Date` , `Details of Actions Taken by FMT-BB` )\VALUES ('MD-MAL_MSAG5200_01 - MD-Malwana - ZTE', ' CRITICAL', 'MD-MAL_MSAG5200_01 - MD-Malwana - ZTE Isolated', 'All customers(49) in above MD-MAL_MSAG5200_01 DSLAM/=3D MSAN ', 'PENDING', '= FMT-BB(A)', ' OPEN', 'PENDING', 'Informed to DGM :kapuru@slt.com.lk')
```

You are missing some backticks and single quotes. This should work.